# Parse PFObject cannot correct remove object for keys?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I want to update one field of my `PFObject` which points to One `PFUser`.

```
PFUser.currentUser().removeObjectForKey("OtherUser")

PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackground()
```

Unfortunately, it is not working.

Does anyone know how to clear some specific contents to one `PFObject`'s field?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it not working"?

Comment: Your code is removing a field from the user, not a user field from another object

Comment: Thank you. Finally, I noticed it removed the field. Some delay occurred on simulator. That's why I thought it not working.

Comment: Please post your solution so that other users are helped as well